# Persistindo em lote em Entidade Many-to-Many com campos extra

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: 
Se eu tiver um relacionamento N pra N ex: Produtos e Moedas.
Na hora que fosse persistir ficaria 1 Produto com uma lista com 10 Moedas.

```
public class Produto {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Moedas> Moedas { get; set; }
}

public class Produto {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Produtos> Produtos { get; set; }
}
```

Se eu persistir o Produto, ele já automaticamente cria o relacionamento desse produto com as 10 moedas.

```
var produto = new Produto() { Nome = "Espécie", Moedas = listaModas }
_context.Produto.Add(produto);
```

Porém e se eu precisar de uma tabela com um campo extra, teria que ficar assim:

```
public class Produto {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProdutoMoeda> ProdutoMoedas { get; set; }
}

public class Produto {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProdutoMoeda> ProdutoMoedas { get; set; }
}

public class ProdutoMoeda {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int MoedaId { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public Moeda Moeda { get; set; }
    public Produto Produto { get; set; }
}
```

Sendo assim eu não consigo mais persistir em lote como conseguia antes.
Como faria pra persistir se recebesse 1 Produto com 10 Moedas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só continuar a lógica.

```
var moedas = _context.Moedas.Where(...).ToList();
var produto = new Produto() 
{ 
    Nome = "Espécie"
};

foreach (var moeda in moedas)
{
    produto.ProdutoMoedas.Add(new ProdutoMoeda 
    {
        Moeda = moeda,
        Nome = "Meu Produto Relacionado a Moeda"
    });
}

_context.Produto.Add(produto);
```

Comment: Opa Cigano, vlw mais uma vez. Mas a dúvida está justamente no produto não ter mais uma lista de Moedas. E sim uma lista de ProdutoMoeda que seria minha tabela gerada a partir de Many-To-Many.

Comment: É só uma questão de nome. Já alterei.

Comment: Vlw Cigano, deu certinho.